# How to autogenerate global ID using AppSync + DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

How do I generate ID automatically when I use `AppSync` and `DynamoDB` as the database source?

I have a type looking like below

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    creator: String!
    createdAt: String!
    like: Int!
    dislike: Int!
    frozen: Boolean!
}
```

and input looking like below

```
input CreatePostInput {
    id: ID!
    creator: String!
    createdAt: String!
    like: Int!
    dislike: Int!
    frozen: Boolean!
}
```

and my mutation is obviously the combination of the two

```
createPost(input: CreatePostInput!): Post
```

However, when I make inserts I have to do something like below

```
mutation createPost{
  createPost(input:{
    id:2
    creator:"some creator"
    createdAt:"some date"
    like:0
    dislike:0
    frozen:false
  }){
    id
    creator
    createdAt
    like
    dislike
    frozen
  }
}
```

There is no way I can insert a post without having to know what the `id` is up to right now. Is there a way I can provide `null` or any random `id` and `DynamoDB` or `AppSync` automatically create the next index before inserting into the table?

> Error generated when I update the `input CreatePostInput` to not
>   accept any `ID`

```
{
  "data": {
    "createPost": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createPost"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key id expected: S actual: NULL (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 629QEM7MH9BRAJ9MHU3FM1S0U3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
    }
  ]
}
```

> My Resolver Template

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        ## If object "id" should come from GraphQL arguments, change to $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.id)
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, update the `createPost` resolver as:

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
  },
  "attributeValues": $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input),
  "condition": {
    "expression": "attribute_not_exists(#id)",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#id": "id",
    },
  },
}
```

Then, remove the `id` field from your `CreatePostInput` input type:

```
input CreatePostInput {
  creator: String!
  createdAt: String!
  like: Int!
  dislike: Int!
  frozen: Boolean!
}
```

Save both the changes and you should be done.

If you're the one of seeing-is-believing guys like me, take a look at this [egghead.io video](https://egghead.io/lessons/graphql-autogenerate-an-id-field-in-graphql-with-appsync-resolvers).

Answer (score 0):

You can auto generate a UUIDv4 using the $util.autoId() velocity helper function. For example, you can write a createPost resolver that uses a server-side generated id like this.

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args)
}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to include that part. My resolver looks exactly same as what you have written. Do you have any suggestions what might be going wrong?

Comment: If you are using $util.autoId() you should not have to pass an id as part of the input. Can you try deleting the Id field from the create input and call the mutation? If you aren't getting an I'd generated for you please make sure you are using $util.autoId()

Comment: yes I have tried that too but it returns the error that I have specified in the question update. Can you please confirm for me if you are using the same methodology in your `AppSync` application and `$util.autoId()` is working for you?

Comment: I have pasted that on my question